# Ignoring a particular file pattern in git

Tags: regex, git, gitignore

I am using git in my project. My home directory contain few files like

```
Title v2.12.12.exe
Title v1.4.21.exe
Title v3.42.11.exe
```

All these starts with `Title v` and ends with `.exe` and contains some version in the middle. What changed should I made in .gitignore to ignore these types of file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried it and the simplest seem to work:

```
Title v*.exe
```

The only caveat is that you may catch more than expected like "Title v-not.a.valid.version.exe"